# Is there any way to add to the help system without developing a plugin

Tags: help-system

I have somewhat customised vim to my needs what I would like to do would be to add a cheatsheet, documenting these customisations and other things I often forget to the vim help system.

I know that it can be extended by plugins is there another way to expand the vim help system? writing a plugin seems overkill for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding a help file is actually fairly easy: as documented in [`:help add-local-help`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#05.5), you plop it in `~/.vim/doc` and then run `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`. That's (part of) what your plugin manager is doing for you when you install a plugin.

You can confirm its been added by running `:help local-additions`; all the local help files should be listed there.

If you need help writing help files, there is some advice in [`:help help-writing`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#help-writing).